# Is the DTC enabled by default in Windows?

Tags: windows, services

I have been reading the documentation provided by Microsoft regarding the Distributed Transaction Coordinator ([DTC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771891.aspx)).

But I am not able to determine whether the DTC service is enabled by default - I want to know its default configuration (Manual vs. Automatic) and any other configuration values in a fresh Windows installation.

Comment: Can you not just to to **Start** | **Run** | Type in **Services.msc** and press **Enter**, sort by the **Name** column, look for **Distributed Transaction Coordinator** and then open to confirm it's status and startup parameter? If you do a fresh install of Windows and as soon as whatever version of Windows you are installing is complete with the media, etc. you are using, do that and this should answer your question.

Comment: It would be my first attempt, but unfortunately I do not have access to Windows installer media, neither virtual machines nor azure due security policies in the company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default *Startup type* of the Distributed Transaction Coordinator service is **Manual**. Therefore, it will only start in one of two circumstances:

1. It is explicitly started, e.g. from the Services management tool. This isn't particularly likely, since it doesn't do anything interesting on its own. Management tools for it, like the Component Services snap-in for MMC, will start it if you open the relevant parts of the program. (The service started when I looked at *Component Services* → *Computers* → *My Computer* → *Distributed Transaction Coordinator*.)
2. A service that depends on it starts. Services that do useful work that requires communication involving the DTC will be registered with a dependency on the DTC service. When a service starts, all the services it depends on will start first. [Further reading at Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/193888).

Answer (score 0):

Per this document: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd337629%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

The default service start type is manual, and the service account is Network Service.